# zsh associative array has multiple keys with the same value

Tags: macos, zsh, zos

I am having trouble with some code and I've discovered that I am getting multiple identical keys in my associative array, which I would have not expected possible.
I have tried to get this behaviour in a simple test case and am coming up short - if I assign a second key/value pair to the associative array, the old one is gone (which I would expect).

Here is the code that prints out the key/value pairs:

```
local key=''
local value=''
for key value in ${(kv)grid}; do
  echo "$key -> $value" >&2
done
```

and here is some of the output (after I sorted it)

```
"1000,1000" -> #
"1000,1000" -> #
"1000,1000" -> #
"1000,1000" -> #
"1000,1001" -> #
"1000,1001" -> #
"1000,1001" -> #
"1000,1001" -> #
"1000,1002" -> #
"1000,1002" -> #
"1000,1002" -> #
"1000,1002" -> #
"1000,1003" -> #
```

You can see there are multiple key/value pairs with the same key (and in some cases the same value too).

This occurs on both z/OS Zsh 5.8.1 and Mac Zsh 5.9

I expect I have a bug in my code, but if someone knows how I can be getting these multiple key/value pairs into the associative array, I would be grateful.

Edit: adding more information as requested:

Here is how I declare the grid:

```
declare -A grid
```

Here is how I set a 'cell' in the grid:

```
set_cell()
{
  local srow=$1
  local scol=$2
  local sc=$3
  local skey="${srow},${scol}"

  grid["${skey}"]="$sc"}
}
```

Here is how I 'get' the value of a cell:

```
get_cell()
{
  local grow=$1
  local gcol=$2
  local gkey="${grow},${gcol}"
  local gval=${grid[(k)"${gkey}"]}
  echo "${gval}"
  return 0
}
```

I call the get and set routines as:

```
  local c
  c=$(get_cell ${row} ${lcol})
```

and:

```
local out='O'
set_cell ${row} ${rcol} "${out}"
```

where the row and col variables are integral.

I also added:

```
echo "Type of grid: ${(t)grid}" >&2
```

just before the loop dumping out the values and I get:

```
Type of grid: association
```

Comment: Something to try: change  `${(kv)grid}` to `"${(kv@)grid}"`. Also, it's often easier to see the contents of a variable with `typeset -p grid`.

Comment: My first guess would be that there's some sort of non-printing characters in there. Try replacing that `echo` command with `printf '%s\n' "$key -> $value" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt >&2` and see if that makes a difference visible.

Comment: Can also do `printf '%s -> %s\n' "${(V)key}" "${(V)value}"` without needing `cat`. Or even do it in the original loop expansion: `${(kvV)grid}` and leave the body alone.

Comment: How is grid defined? Are you sure it is not a normal array?

Comment: What do you see when you do a `declare -p grid`?

Comment: @TomRegner Even if the `k` flag worked with regular arrays, they're not going to have keys (indices?) like `"1000,1000"`

Comment: The symptoms can be reproduced with a standard array:  `typeset -a grid=('"1000,1000"' '#' '"1000,1000"' '#'); printf "%s -> %s\n" ${(kv)grid}`. @TomRegner

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas ! I will dig in.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue using the `set_cell` function, so the problem may be in some of the calls to it. Try `typeset -p grid` - it should show you exactly what is in the array, while `print`, and `echo` may not.

Comment: Also, `grid["${skey}"]="$sc"}` has a trailing `}`, and It's probably best to quote all of the arguments in the call to set_cell: `set_cell "${row}" "${rcol}" "${out}"`

Comment: I figured out my problem. Very silly of me - and I have done this before so I should know better. I was calling my function with the form:
`x=$(get_cell "${row}" "${col}")`and then I was echo'ing out the result. Because of the `$(..)` syntax so that I could save the output, it was also accessing the global variable 'grid' to do the update, but I wasn't getting the global grid updated. So I will change the code to just return the value as an integer and get rid of the `$(...)` syntax